# How can I change log level for rabbitmq queue category using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I would like to change the level of log in my Rabbitmq queue category. I use docker-compose to deploy it.

I would like to have this conf in my rabbitmq.conf : log.queue.level=warn

```
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
        container_name: rabbitmq
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/rabbitmq/etc/:/etc/rabbitmq/
            - ./.docker/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
            - ./.docker/rabbitmq/logs/:/var/log/rabbitmq/
        environment:
            RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
        ports:
            - 5672:5672
            - 15672:15672
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [dockerhub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq)

> Additional Configuration
> If configuration is required, it is recommended to supply an appropriate /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf file (see the "Configuration File(s)" section of the RabbitMQ documentation for more details), for example via bind-mount, Docker Configs, or a short Dockerfile with a COPY instruction.

> Alternatively, it is possible to use the RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS environment variable, whose syntax is described in section 7.8 ("Configuring an Application") of the Erlang OTP Design Principles User's Guide (the appropriate value for -ApplName is -rabbit) [...]

For the sake a readability, you should probably mount a `rabbitmq.conf` configuration file into your rabbitmq container.